# How to customize django-rosetta admn page

Tags: django, django-admin, django-rosetta

Since when I open django-rosetta on the admin page by setting `ROSETTA_SHOW_AT_ADMIN_PANEL = True` in the settings file. I am able to open it on the admin page, but when it opens it takes full-page, and I am unable to go back to the homepage(as there is no button) except when I press the back button of the browser. Is there any solution for this, or do I have to override the rosetta home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually i have to override html page for this, no other option :(